# Issue with the Massberg Analog-Matched Low Pass Filter

Tags: filter-design, lowpass-filter, octave, biquad

Implemented the filter mentioned in title using Octave and couple sources [Vicanek](https://vicanek.de/articles/BiquadFits.pdf) and [Zeitlin](https://github.com/larzeitlin/MassbergLPF) ([LPF.cpp](https://github.com/larzeitlin/MassbergLPF/blob/master/LPF.cpp)). Got filter working otherwise but, ... when tested the responses against 'analog model' of the LP filter I noticed there an issue with range of Q values starting from `>sqrt(0.5)` to close ~2.0. Here are few plots showing the issue:

[image]

[image]

[image]

What/where is the problem?

**EDIT:**

Looks like the issue is in Omega_s calculation where Vicanek and Zeitlin uses

```
Q > sqrt(0.5)
```

as condition value when it should be

```
Q > sqrt(5)
```

instead. At least after making this change responses looks more OK:

[image]

*(various Q values used with various cutoff frequencies, (500hz/0.4, 1k/0.707, 4k/4, 7k/6 and 12k/12))*

... but, is it OK, because of this change I did (and more) has been corrected already once by Will Pirkle in [Designing Audio Effect Plug-Ins in C++, With Digital Audio Signal Processing Theory](http://www.worldcat.org/title/designing-audio-effect-plug-ins-in-c-with-digital-audio-signal-processing-theory/oclc/898599503?referer=di&ht=edition) ([errata](http://www.willpirkle.com/support/errata/)):

> There is an error in the calculation of the g1, gz and gp coefficients
> for the Massberg LPF, second order only. There is also an error in the
> check for Q, it should reference the square root of 0.5, not 5.0. See
> the Bonus Projects on the Projects Page for the complete code for this
> LPF with corrections. Thanks to astute readers Christian Floisand and
> Ernst Oosterveld for finding and reporting this! The fully [corrected
> equations are here](http://www.willpirkle.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/MassbergCorrection.jpg) .

Any suggestions which is the issue there?

Has anyone got implemented this filter with success by just following either those two sources I mention or the W. Prikle book (with or without the corrected code)?